# TreeList - hide nodes when children do not exist

Tags: vb.net, recursion, devexpress, treelist, xtratreelist

I use the DevExpress Framework for development in VB.net.
I am facing issues with the DevExpress TreeList control, which is not a problem with the control itself but the algorithm for hiding specific nodes. I am not able to find a suitable solution.

**Problem:**

> A checkbox fires the event to hide nodes which do not have nodes with
> the [Type] "GLAccount". The code snipped below works in as much as only the parents of GLAccounts will be hidden but it does not inherits the information upwards (to the grandparents and their parents) to make them invisible as well.
> As soon as there aren't any nodes with the [Type] "GLAccount" the parents should be not visible, but if sibbling nodes have "GLAccounts" then not all parents should be invisble.

Checkbox event:

```
Private Sub BarCheckItem1_CheckedChanged_2(sender As Object, e As ItemClickEventArgs) Handles bciHideEmptyAccounts.CheckedChanged
        If CType(bciHideEmptyAccounts.Checked, Boolean) Then
            hideNodesRecursive(treeListLeft.Nodes, False)
        Else
            hideNodesRecursive(treeListLeft.Nodes, True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Sub being fired by the Checkbox event depending whether Checkbox value is true/false:

```
 Private Sub hideNodesRecursive(ByVal nodes As TreeListNodes, ByVal bHide As Boolean)
        For Each node As TreeListNode In nodes
            If node.HasChildren Then
                hideNodesRecursive(node.Nodes, bHide)
            Else
                If Not CType(node.GetValue("Type"), String) = "GLAccount" Then
                    node.Visible = bHide
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Use Case 1: Structure given shows different level of nodes. GLAccounts do only occure in the last level (they do not have childs).
The blue highlighting shows that the event hides the nodes properly.
[image]

Result: Previously blue highlighted node disappeared.
[image]

Uase Case 2: again, blue highligthed nodes will be properly hidden, but the orange node is still visible.
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Think your issue is in this line `If node.HasChildren Then`.  I'm guessing that even though the child nodes are hidden they are still there so HasChildren is evaluating to true.  You proably need to extend that conditional to include hidden nodes

Comment: i think you did not get my problem right. hidden nodes are not the problem. the problem is that only the parents will be invisible but the grandparents will not and even their parents will not (if suitable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visibility of each node can be evaluated by the logical OR of all its Childs. So, even one of its Childs is visible (has a value of "GLAccount") it should be visible.

I slightly changed the BarCheckItem1_CheckedChanged routine. Also added a simple sub to show all nodes (Show_Nodes) because cannot found any method in DevExpress documentation for setting the visibilty of all treelist nodes.

Can not check the code by the time of this post, but it is logically correct.

```
Private Sub BarCheckItem1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bciHideEmptyAccounts.CheckedChanged
    treeListLeft.BeginUpdate()
    IF bciHideEmptyAccounts.Checked THEN
        hideNodesRecursive(TreeListLeft.Nodes)
    ELSE
        Show_Nodes(TreeListLeft.nodes)
    END IF
    treeListLeft.EndUpdate()
End Sub


Private Sub hideNodesRecursive(ByVal nodes As TreeListNodes)
    For Each node As TreeListNode In nodes
        node.visible= CSTR(node.GetValue("Type")).equals("GLAccount")
        IF NOT isnothing(node.parentnode) THEN
            node.parentnode.visible= (node.parentnode.visible OR node.visible)
        END IF
        hideNodesRecursive(node.Nodes)
    Next
End Sub


SUB Show_Nodes(nodes AS treelistnodes)
    FOR EACH node AS treelistnode IN nodes
        node.visible= TRUE
        Show_Nodes(node. Nodes)
    NEXT
END SUB
```

EDIT:
treeListLeft.BeginUpdate() / treeListLeft.EndUpdate() added according to the point mentioned in comment by [smartini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9121235/smartini)

Comment: thank you, it works! but I have enormous performance issues with this solution.
it takes apprx. 2 minutes for the hiding process with 5000 Nodes of which 1000 are of type GLAccounts.
solution for anyone else is to put "treeListLeft.BeginUpdate()" before running the recursive funtion and "treeListLeft.EndUpdate()" at the end of the BarCheckItem function. it now takes 1 second.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. I edited the code to represent your guidance.